# NLTK ne_tree Word Tokenize chunk from Column rows (Python/Pandas/Jupyter)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nltk, jupyter

I just started learning about the Natural Language Took kit. I'm trying to categorize words. I'm basically looking for things Persons, Places, and Organizations.

So far defining a single line of text works in the script.

```
ex = 'John'
ne_tree =  nltk.ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(ex)))
print(ne_tree)
```

Output:

```
(S (PERSON John/NNP))
```

My question am I able to specify an entire column with this script?

My table is as below.

ex2:

```
Order   Text
    0   John
    1   Chicago
    2   stuff
    3   question
```

Order is basically the index I created. The idea is later I can break sentences down to words, maintain a key, and melt. Text is what I want to tokenize.

When I run this code I get the below error. Perhaps I'm calling it incorrectly, and I need to specify the column? Thanks for the help.

```
ne_tree =  nltk.ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(ex2)))
print(ne_tree)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-5d4582e937dd> in <module>
----> 1 ne_tree =  nltk.ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(ex3)))
      2 print(ne_tree)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py in word_tokenize(text, language, preserve_line)
    142     :type preserve_line: bool
    143     """
--> 144     sentences = [text] if preserve_line else sent_tokenize(text, language)
    145     return [
    146         token for sent in sentences for token in _treebank_word_tokenizer.tokenize(sent)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py in sent_tokenize(text, language)
    104     """
    105     tokenizer = load('tokenizers/punkt/{0}.pickle'.format(language))
--> 106     return tokenizer.tokenize(text)
    107 
    108 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in tokenize(self, text, realign_boundaries)
   1275         Given a text, returns a list of the sentences in that text.
   1276         """
-> 1277         return list(self.sentences_from_text(text, realign_boundaries))
   1278 
   1279     def debug_decisions(self, text):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in sentences_from_text(self, text, realign_boundaries)
   1329         follows the period.
   1330         """
-> 1331         return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]
   1332 
   1333     def _slices_from_text(self, text):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1329         follows the period.
   1330         """
-> 1331         return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]
   1332 
   1333     def _slices_from_text(self, text):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in span_tokenize(self, text, realign_boundaries)
   1319         if realign_boundaries:
   1320             slices = self._realign_boundaries(text, slices)
-> 1321         for sl in slices:
   1322             yield (sl.start, sl.stop)
   1323 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in _realign_boundaries(self, text, slices)
   1360         """
   1361         realign = 0
-> 1362         for sl1, sl2 in _pair_iter(slices):
   1363             sl1 = slice(sl1.start + realign, sl1.stop)
   1364             if not sl2:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in _pair_iter(it)
    316     it = iter(it)
    317     try:
--> 318         prev = next(it)
    319     except StopIteration:
    320         return

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in _slices_from_text(self, text)
   1333     def _slices_from_text(self, text):
   1334         last_break = 0
-> 1335         for match in self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text):
   1336             context = match.group() + match.group('after_tok')
   1337             if self.text_contains_sentbreak(context):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too apply the function to each row value

```
ex2['results'] = ex2.Text.apply(lambda x: nltk.ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(x))))
```